# android POST - Unexpected response code 403

Tags: android, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I want to add user inputs to web server. I use PHP and MySQL to store data. The app POSTs data to http://url_address/getData.php .

On localhost while I POST to http://192.168.1.38/getData.php everything works OK and data being inserted to database.

I also used https://www.000webhost.com/ to test my code and the data is inserted to that server. I could see from phpmyadmin.

But when I change address to my web address http://mywebsite.com/getData.php I get an error 
E/Volley: [208] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://... I use hosting from https://ifastnet.com/

I googled and found that I have to change my httpd.conf file as belov:

```
<Directory />
         AllowOverride none
         Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But I use shared hosting plan and I cannot change httpd.conf , insted I should use .htaccess file. But when I use .htaccess I get below error:

> A 500 error has occured
>
> 500 errors are generally caused by one of the following two problems.
>
> 1) A bad entry in the site .htaccess file, if you are the webmaster
>   try logging into your cPanel, and use the file manager to rename your
>   .htaccess file if this fixes the error you should then check the
>   contents of the .htaccess file / roll back any recent changes.
>
> 2) A php error / code error also causes a 500 error, you can try
>   enabling 'PHP display_errors' by following this guide Enable Display
>   errors
>
> If after trying both of the above solutions and you are still seeing
>   the 500 error please do contact support

help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet. maybe hosting provider made some restrictions.